# The meaning of 'c(min =0, max =0)' in vapply()

Tags: r, function, range, pre-allocation

```
salaries <- list(leaders = c(250, 200), assistant = 100, members = c(300, 200, 180, 120, 100))


> vapply(salaries, range, c(min=0, max=0))
leaders assistant members
min     200       100     100
max     250       100     300
```

In this script, the results are always the same regardless of the min and max values, so I wonder what '=0' means here.

What I've tried.

```
> vapply(salaries, range, c(min=0.1, max=1))
leaders assistant members
min     200       100     100
max     250       100     300


> vapply(salaries, range, c(min=2, max=1))
leaders assistant members
min     200       100     100
max     250       100     300


> vapply(salaries, range, c(min=1000, max=1000))
leaders assistant members
min     200       100     100
max     250       100     300
```

Answer (score 1):

Realize what third argument of `vapply` actually means.

Consider this `for` loop. To code it efficiently, we pre-allocate memory, i.e. we create an empty numeric array `m` (aka matrix) that we fill up later. `m` will have number of rows according to the output of the `range` function which is of length `2`, and number of columns according to the length of the object we will loop over, `length(salaries)`.

```
> m <- array(0, dim=c(2, length(salaries)), dimnames=list(NULL, names(salaries)))
> for (i in seq_along(salaries)) {
+   m[, i] <- range(salaries[i])
+ }
> m
     leaders assistant members
[1,]     200       100     100
[2,]     250       100     300
```

Since `vapply` automatically detects `length(salaries)`, we only need to specify type and length of the output of the `range` function, which is exactly what we're doing in the third argument. How exactly you do that is up to you; you could do `c(0, 0)`, `c(min=2, max=1)`, `rep.int(0, 2)`—I personally use `numeric(length=2L)` (aka `double(.)`) which clarifies best, that a numeric vector of length 2 is wanted.

```
> vapply(X=salaries, FUN=range, FUN.VALUE=numeric(2L))
     leaders assistant members
[1,]     200       100     100
[2,]     250       100     300
```

Note, that, since your results will be of type `double`, doing `FUN.VALUE=integer(2L)` would fail.

Pre-allocation with `vapply` results in a much faster calculation than using `sapply`, which gives the same result but is slower without allocation.

```
> sapply(X=salaries, FUN=range)
     leaders assistant members
[1,]     200       100     100
[2,]     250       100     300
```

### Benchmark

To show that this actually makes a difference, here a benchmark of the examples.

```
> salaries_l <- salaries[sample.int(length(salaries), 5e5, replace=TRUE)]
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   vapply=vapply(X=salaries_l, FUN=range, FUN.VALUE=numeric(2L)),
+   sapply=sapply(X=salaries_l, FUN=range),
+   `for`={
+     m <- array(0, dim=c(2, length(salaries_l)), dimnames=list(NULL, names(salaries_l)))
+     for (i in seq_along(salaries_l)) {
+       m[, i] <- range(salaries_l[i])
+     }
+     m
+   },
+   check='identical',
+   times=10L
+ )

$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: seconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 vapply 1.538160 1.547140 1.687497 1.564839 1.880192 1.933732    10  a 
 sapply 1.746593 1.771601 1.851726 1.818901 1.944878 1.980924    10  a 
    for 2.669507 2.689559 2.860819 2.744123 3.142934 3.150242    10   b
```